How CCD receives lasers in laser machining?
The diagram below illustrates the system uses a beam splitter that sends the beam to a camera for real-time measurement.

What I'm curious about is how the laser beam is directed onto the ccd, will it go like in figure 1 or figure 2 and how the beam splitter directs a small percentage of the beam to the camera, while most of the beam goes through the integrated power sensors.

Cite:
Hajjarian, Z., Nadkarni, S. Evaluating the Viscoelastic Properties of Tissue from Laser Speckle Fluctuations. Sci Rep 2, 316 (2012). https://doi.org/10.1038/srep00316

Its number 1. The laser is an illumination source and the camera is just looking at the sample.

@JoséAndrade Thank you.
